# How to correctly use two if statements in Google Sheets or Excel?

Tags: excel, if-statement, google-sheets, compare

I tried doing the following in google sheets for cell F3

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(E3, "Win"), D3/(C3*-1/100)), IF(REGEXMATCH(E3, "Loss"), D3*-1)
```

But it says Formula parse error (particurly when I add the 2nd IF part)

Does anyone know how to make it do one formula if cell E3 says Win, but another if it says Loss?

Answer (score 1):

Fix parenthesis:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(E2,"Win"),D3/(C3*(-1/100)),IF(REGEXMATCH(E2,"Loss"),D3*(-1)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much